# Ansible replace text in file

Tags: ansible

So ive been tasked with replaceing zabbix server. To do so i have to modify zabbix_agent file in all server and there are many. Tho in this job is the first time i see ansible so i need some help. And i am using ansible-playbook.

In zabbix_agentd.conf file there is the old zabbix conf:

```
HostMetadata=Linux
PidFile=/var/run/zabbix/zabbx_agentd.pid
LogFile=/var/log/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.log
LogFileSize=0
Server=zabbix.company.com
ServerActive=zabbix.company.com
HostnameItem=system.hostname
Include=/etc/zabbix_agentd.d/
```

Now i need to replace "Server" and "ServerActive" to "zabbix2.company.com"

I have tried various codes from this page to work for my needs but so far it has failed. No clue what im doing wrong

Comment: What did you try and what went wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this one

```yaml
    - lineinfile:
        path: /etc/zabbix_agentd.conf
        regexp: '^\s*{{ key }}\s*=(.*)$'
        line: '{{ key }}={{ value }}'
      notify: reload zabix
      loop:
        - {key: 'Server', value: 'zabbix2.company.com'}
        - {key: 'ServerActive', value: 'zabbix2.company.com'}
```

---

Notes

- Path is required; probably /etc/zabbix_agentd.conf ?
- It is not necessary to search the white-space `\s*` in `regexp`. However, it would match and fix potential spaces in the configuration.
- Create and notify a handler `reload zabix` when anything changed. See [Handlers: Running Operations On Change](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_intro.html#handlers-running-operations-on-change).
- Take a look at [Zabix](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/modules/list_of_monitoring_modules.html#zabbix) modules.

Comment: Thank you for quick reply. Yes i forgot the path, it is /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf. But that much i could change myself. Ill take a look at it and try it out when i can.

Answer (score 0):

I have manged to solve this issue using this code.

```
---
tasks:
- name: 'replace line'
  lineinfile:
    dest: /etc/zabbix/zabbix_agentd.conf
    regexp: '^(.*)Server=zabbix.company.com(.*)$'
    line: 'Server=zabbix2.company.com'
    backrefs: yes
```